# Why does providing initial parameters in GenSA always give same result regardless of seed?

Tags: r, simulated-annealing

I don't seem to understand how the simulated annealing algorithm used by GenSA always arrives to the same solution when argument `par` is provided:

```
library(GenSA)

Rastrigin <- function(x) {
  sum(x^2 - 10 * cos(2 * pi  * x)) + 10 * length(x)
}

niter <- 10
sol <- data.frame(with.par = NaN*seq(niter))
sol$without.par <- NaN
for(i in seq(niter)){
  fit1 <- GenSA(
    par = c(1,1),
    fn = Rastrigin, 
    lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), 
    upper = c(5.12, 5.12)
  )
  fit2 <- GenSA(
    fn = Rastrigin, 
    lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), 
    upper = c(5.12, 5.12)
  )
  sol$with.par[i] <- min(as.data.frame(fit1$trace.mat)$function.value)
  sol$without.par[i] <- min(as.data.frame(fit2$trace.mat)$function.value)
}
sol
```

resulting in:

```
       with.par  without.par
1  2.209873e-09 2.142819e-09
2  2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
3  2.209873e-09 2.142819e-09
4  2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
5  2.209873e-09 2.142819e-09
6  2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
7  2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
8  2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
9  2.209873e-09 2.209870e-09
10 2.209873e-09 2.209873e-09
```

Even when `par = NULL`, there is quite a high degree of convergence. Either way, does this not go against the idea of a random search in SA?

Answer (score 1):

After digging in the [source code of `GenSA`](https://github.com/cran/GenSA) a little bit, I have realized that you are correct. If you set the `par`, you will always get the same result. The seed of R is only used in the following lines [here](https://github.com/cran/GenSA/blob/master/R/GenSA.R):

```
     else {
        if (con$verbose) {
            cat("Initializing par with random data inside bounds\n")
        }
        par <- vector()
#initialize par with random values in the bounds
            par <- lower + runif(length(lower))*(upper-lower)
    }
```

which generates the random initial point if it's not specified, before passing it into the C++ engine. So if you set the `par` yourself, the GenSA will always return the same result because the C++ engine is seeded seperately from R.

This does not mean it's not using random search though, check how convergence happens:

[image]

It **is** a random search, but if you explicity set the `par`, you will use the same seed, hence get the same result every time.

```
library(GenSA)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

Rastrigin <- function(x) {
  sum(x^2 - 10 * cos(2 * pi  * x)) + 10 * length(x)
}

fit1 <- GenSA(
    par = c(1,1),
    fn = Rastrigin, 
    lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), 
    upper = c(5.12, 5.12)
  )
fit2 <- GenSA(
    fn = Rastrigin, 
    lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), 
    upper = c(5.12, 5.12)
  )

res = data.table(fit1$trace.mat)[,.SD[1,], .(nb.steps)]
res2 = data.table(fit2$trace.mat)[,.SD[1,], .(nb.steps)]
p = ggplot() +
          geom_line(data = res[1:250,], aes( x=nb.steps, y=function.value, colour = "par")) +
          geom_line(data = res2[1:250,], aes( x=nb.steps, y=function.value, colour = "no-par")) 

print(p)
```

If you run this code multiple times, blue line will be exactly the same every time, while red line will change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - The code from the function that you show is only calculating the par if missing. You say that seed is calculated differently in C++; does this mean that the seed is always being set identically, and that only a random initial par will determine a different search pattern?

Comment: @Marcinthebox yes exactly, that's what I think. If you use the same par you will get the same result every time with the same search pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The package has been updated to version 1.1.7 including the "seed" option in the control list argument of the GenSA function to seed the internal random generator.
Best regards,

Sylvain.